# find string from a group of files

Tags: powershell

I have a group of txt files contain similar strings like this:

```
Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
Product Part No.: *****
Installed from 'Compliance Checked Product' media.
Product ID: 0000-0000-0000  match to CD Key data
CD Key: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
Computer Name: COMP001
Registered Owner: ABC
Registered Organization:

Microsoft Office Professional Edition 2003
Product ID: 00000-00000-00000-00000
CD Key: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```

How may I pick all office keys one time and save into another file?

My code:

```
$content = Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\New folder' -Recurse |
           where Name -like "b*" |
           select name
Get-Content $content
```

I get a list of files name but it wouldn't run for `Get-Content`.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *particular* problem (in your code) do you need help with? Regular expressions are a common approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code. Reading code in comments sucks

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't work, because `$content` contains a list of custom objects with one property (`name`) containing just the file name without path. Since you're apparently not listing the files in the current working directory, but some other folder (`S:\New Folder`), you need the full path to those files (property `FullName`) if you want to be able to read them. Also, the property isn't expanded automatically. You must either expand it when enumerating the files:

```
$content = Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\New folder' -Recurse |
           Where-Object { $_.Name -like "b*" } |
           Select-Object -Expand FullName
Get-Content $content
```

or when passing the value to `Get-Content`:

```
$content = Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\New folder' -Recurse |
           Where-Object { $_.Name -like "b*" } |
           Select-Object FullName
Get-Content $content.FullName
```

---

With that out of the way, none of the code you have does even attempt to extract the data you're looking for. Assuming that the license information blocks in your files is always separated by 2 or more consecutive line breaks you could split the content of the files at consecutive line breaks and extract the information with a regular expression like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\New folder' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.Name -like "b*"
} | ForEach-Object {
    # split content of each file into individual license information fragments
    (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -split '(\r?\n){2,}' | Where-Object {
        # filter for fragments that contain the string "Microsoft Office" and
        # match the line beginning with "CD Key: " in those fragments
        $_ -like '*Microsoft Office*' -and
        $_ -match '(?m)(?<=^CD Key: ).*'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        # remove leading/trailing whitespace from the extracted key
        $matches[0].Trim()
    }
} | Set-Content 'C:\output.txt'
```

`(\r?\n){2,}` is a regular expression that matches 2 or more consecutive line breaks (both Windows and Unix style).

`(?m)(?<=^CD Key: ).*` is a regular expression that matches a line beginning with the string `CD Key:` and returns the rest of the line after that string. `(?<=...)` is a so-called positive lookbehind assertion that is used for matching a pattern without including it in the returned value. `(?m)` is a regular expression option that allows `^` to match the beginning of a line inside a multiline string instead of just the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -filter "*.txt" | 
    %{select-string -Path $_.FullName -Pattern "CD Key:" } | select line | export-csv "c:\temp\found.csv" -notype
```

Comment: thank you Esperento57.    can I save the title of the txt file infront of every one,cause that's the computer name. So it cold be like : computer name--cd key

Answer (score 0):

If you want computer information you can do it (-context take N rows before and M rows after example -context 3, 2 take 3 before and 2 after) :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -filter "*.txt" | 
    %{select-string -Path $_.FullName -Pattern "CD Key:" -context 6,0  } | where {$_.Context.PreContext[0] -like 'Computer Name:*'} |
        select Line, @{Name="Computer";E={($_.Context.PreContext[0] -split ':')[1] }} | export-csv "c:\temp\found.csv" -notype
```

Answer (score 0):

Or classically:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file -filter "*.txt" | foreach{

$CurrenFile=$_.FullName

#split current file rows to 2 column with ':' like delimiter
$KeysValues=get-content $CurrenFile | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ":"  -PropertyNames Key, Value

#if file contains CD Key, its good file
if ($KeysValues -ne $null -and $KeysValues[2].Key -eq 'CD Key')
{
    #build object with asked values
    $Object=[pscustomobject]@{

    File=$CurrenFile
    ComputerName=$KeysValues[3].Value
    OfficeKey=$KeysValues[7].Value
    }

    #send objet to standard output
    $Object
}

} | export-csv "c:\temp\found.csv" -notype
```